# Increased file size while copying from windows to ubuntu

Tags: filesystem

I copied few video files in mkv format from windows to ubuntu. In windows the size of files is shown 20GB and in ubuntu it shows 21.6GB. what can be the reason for this difference in file size?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibibyte